# What is the format for PHPStan's "phpVersion" config option?

Tags: php, phpstan

I've been searching and reading and hunting and pulling my hair. This is the only mention of `phpVersion`: https://phpstan.org/config-reference#phpversion

```
If you want to analyse a codebase as if it was written for a different PHP version than you’re currently running, change the phpVersion parameter:

parameters:
    phpVersion: 70400 # PHP 7.4
```

What the...? "70400"? Why this weird format? Does that mean that PHP 8.1 is supposed to be written as "80100"? This really confuses me. I've never see this format before, and it's not mentioned with one single word.

Also, I *have* to put this into the .neon config? I cannot specify it on the command line? That really further complicates things needlessly.

Answer (score 4):

It’s the same format the `PHP_VERSION_ID` constant uses.

So you can just type `php -r "echo PHP_VERSION_ID . PHP_EOL;"` to get it.

If you want to emulate another version, you can do:

```php
$otherVersion = "8.0.0";
$version = explode('.', $otherVersion);

echo $version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2];
# would print 80000
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using **phpVersion**:

From the phpstan documentation:

> PHPStan will automatically infer the **config.platform.php** version from the last **composer.json** file it can find, if not configured in the PHPStan configuration file.

https://phpstan.org/config-reference#phpversion

---

While you can define the platform PHP version in your phpstan file, another possibility is to set the PHP version in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1.13"
        }
    },
}
```

This way you can set it in one place, it will also influence what is installed with `composer install`.

You probably don't want to set the platform PHP version permanently in the `composer.json` (which is also not recommended for libraries because it makes it very inflexible). But you can set it temporarily in your CI pipelines, for example like this:

```
- composer validate
- composer config platform.php "8.1.13"
- composer install
- ....
- run phpstan ...
- ...
- composer config --unset platform.php
- composer config --unset platform
```

Using variable for the PHP version you can run checks for several versions.