# Phpstan analysis fails as part of the Gitlab pipeline

Tags: php, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline, phpstan

Phpstan analysis fails when I run it as part of the Gitlab pipeline, it passes locally. I'm talking about the analysis and not the running of the command itself. I do not get 'command not found' or 'phpstan.neon' not found errors, but rather the analyzer returns all kinds of errors that I put in the baseline.

What I did, locally:

- ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon // fails
- ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon --generate-baseline
- ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon // passes

My phpstan.neon looks like:

```
includes:
    - phpstan-baseline.neon

parameters:
    level: 5
    paths:
        - src
```

and my pipeline looks like:

```
... composer job here

phpstan:
    stage: code_quality
    needs:
        - composer
    script:
        - php vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon --no-progress
```

I expected the job to pass, but I get:

> [ERROR] Found 767 errors

The errors are a combination of stuff that is wrong with the code itself but also errors caused by the baseline: "Ignored error pattern  was not matched in reported errors."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). compare `php --version` and `composer diag` on both systems, maybe you can spot something already. Pin the composer and the PHP version in your build. Use a build manager that runs both locally as well as remotely so that you don't need to re-implement build stages.

Comment: Everything that chatgpt/devillucifer mention in the answer below is the same. The composer version differs a bit but php is version 8.1 vs 8.2, I'll look into that to see if that's the issue. Will let you know

Comment: my guess is difference in the php version then. and it may be indirect (check composer system packages for that matter, e.g. platform the same php version in composer.json, so that tools like phpstan can know (no idea if they have interest to, but if, then composer.json should be leading)).

Comment: Ah, here is the platform thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74912225/367456

Comment: Did you commit the baseline?

Comment: I used an image that my company uses for various projects. It has php v8.1.7, locally I'm using v8.1.16. I also added config.platform.php = 8.1.16 to my composer.json. So far still no luck. I'm going to see if I can get the php version the same down to the patch (though I think a difference in patch shouldn't matter?)

Comment: @AlexHowansky I did, it's what made most sense to me too. But if it wasn't (or it's not readable) phpstan would've thrown an error because I include it in my phpstan.neon

Comment: difference in php version isn't the issue, I'm using the exact same version and still the same result

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Johnson55: Patch version should not matter (last time it mattered to me was only in PHP 5.1.x, just saying that it _can_ matter but from your error description so far, I would consider not - but 8.1/8.2 can give you real differences). I'd keep config.platform.php setting, even if it did not made a difference because you can use it to show the intended PHP version _and_ phpstan operates on it. Another clarification question: Do you commit composer.lock with dev dependencies and use it in the (remote) build? Or do you update in the remote build? ("composer job here" hides all details)

Answer (score 0):

Please check paths. Where you create phpstan-baseline.neon when run
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon --generate-baseline
(you can write path in this command also, it need because baseline will have path from place where you create it)

and try use this path in run script string
php vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -c phpstan.neon --no-progress